Why does the Bloch sphere have a radius of 1?
Why does the Bloch sphere have a radius of 1?
Thank you so much! I am a quantum newbie, so forgive me if this is basic.

Downvotes: why? It seems to be an earnestly asked question.

To the question itself: the radius of a point on or in the Bloch sphere serves as a measure of the fidelity, which is bounded between 0 and 1. A points on the surface of the sphere corresponds to a pure qubit with fidelity = 1, while a point inside corresponds to a qubit in some mixed state, with fidelity <1 (but $\ge$ 0.)

Just to add, a pure single qubit state has to be described by a unit vector so that sum of probabilities of measurement of states 0 and 1 is 1. This may be helpful to understand Bloch sphere better: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/37905/what-is-the-input-when-simulating-a-quantum-state/37909#37909,  https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9404/find-the-theta-and-phi-values-on-the-bloch-sphere-corresponding-to-the-sta, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10303/how-is-a-qubit-represented-on-a-bloch-sphere/10304#10304

@MarkSpinelli: Absolutely agree, no point in downvoting. Everybody has to start learn from beginning.

Thank you so much for the help!!

But, does that mean that a Bloch sphere cannot be plotted anywhere other than the origin of a cartesian plane? Or does that just mean that the Bloch sphere can be plotted anywhere, but it must be a unit sphere?
